# Simple download manager based on Youtube-dl

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

There is a personal program of mine which logs in, scrape links and then download them. The downloader part is based on `Youtube-dl` and I think it's a smell code. Is there any way to improve this code?

```
import requests
import subprocess
import getpass
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import argparse 


def Login(url, login_route, username, password):

    URL = url
    LOGIN_ROUTE = login_route

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': '',
        'origin': URL,
        'referer': URL + LOGIN_ROUTE,
    }

    request_session = requests.session()

    csrf_token = request_session.get(URL).cookies['csrftoken']

    login_payload = {
        'hidden_username': username,
        'password': password,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token
    }

    login_request = request_session.post(
        URL + LOGIN_ROUTE, headers=headers, data=login_payload)
    
    # !
    msg = (
        f'You have logged in successfully {login_request.status_code}' if login_request.status_code == 200 else
        f'Error {login_request.status_code}' 
    )

    print(msg)
    

def get_user_input():

    url = 'https://maktabkhooneh.org/signin/?next=/dashboard/'
    username = getpass.getpass('Username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
    login_route = '/auth/login-authentication'

    return(Login(url, login_route, username, password))


def Scraper(page_url):

    Page_URL = page_url

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': ''
    }

    page = requests.get(
        Page_URL,
        headers=headers,
    )
    soup = bs(page.text, "html.parser")

    URL_List = []
    link_count = 0
    for a_tag in soup.select('a[href^="/course/"]'):

        links = "https://maktabkhooneh.org" + a_tag["href"]

        URL_List.append(links)
        link_count += 1

    return URL_List


def Downloader(url_list):

    URL_List = Scraper(url_list)
    download_count = 0
    for links in URL_List:
        command = f"youtube-dl {links}"
        result = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
        
        # !
        if result == 0:
             download_count += 1
             return('\nReturned Value', result)

    return(f'\n{download_count} file(s) have been downloaded')



page_url = 'https://maktabkhooneh.org/course/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%86-%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%86-Andrew-NG-mk1085/%D9%81%D8%B5%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%82%D8%AF%D9%85%D9%87-ch3364/%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%88-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%A2%D9%85%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF-%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%86/'

Login_ = input('Login required Website [Y], [N]? ')
# !
if Login_ == 'y' or 'Y':
    get_user_input()

list_len = len(Scraper(page_url))
# !
Download_Permission = input(
    f'\n{list_len} link(s) have been extracted. Do you want to DOWNLOAD them [Y], [N]? ')
# !
if Download_Permission == 'y' or 'Y':
    Downloader(page_url)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issues

The first one is the use of the `or` operator. If you wish to compare a variable with two values, you will have to write the comparison operator twice.
For instance,

```py
if Login_ == 'y' or 'Y':
  ...
```

should be write as:

```py
if Login_ == 'y' or Login_ == 'Y':
```

Also, it seems you are returning from the `Downloader` function before iterating though all links (whenever the first process finishes correcly):

```py
...
if result == 0:
  download_count += 1
  # This will return after one commad executes successfully
  return('\nReturned Value', result)
```

## Code style

Now, regarding code smells and style, in python there is [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), a general guide for code style.

For example, functions/methods and variable names should start with lowecase (`Login` should be called `login`).

Also, in the `Login` function, you are assigning the values of the `url` and `login_route` parameters to `URL` and `LOGIN_ROUTE` but they do not seem to serve for anything special. You could just use the function's parameters directly:

```py
...
headers = {
 'User-Agent': '',
  'origin': url,
  'referer': url + login_route,
}
...
csrf_token = request_session.get(url).cookies['csrftoken']
```

Same goes for `Page_URL` in `Scraper`.

Moreover, `return` should be used as a statement, rather than with function notation:

```py
def myFunction():
  return 0
```

Is better than:

```py
def myFunction():
  return(0)
```

## Readability

Lastly, I would say this assignment in `Login` is not quite readable:

```py
msg = (
        f'You have logged in successfully {login_request.status_code}' if login_request.status_code == 200 else
        f'Error {login_request.status_code}' 
    )
```

Language features are there for when they are useful, but readability is key and should be kept in mind. I would write that assignment as a simple `if-else`:

```py
if login_request.status_code == 200:
  msg = f'You have logged in successfully {login_request.status_code}'
else:
  msg = f'Error {login_request.status_code}'
```